# Sonarqube gives node.js error while running sonar-scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

While running sonar-scanner via Jenkins, we are getting the following error message. Jenkins and Sonarqube have been installed in Window Server 2008 OS. I have also tried installed node.js in the server but still, I am getting the same error message.

What are we missing? And why do we need this Node.js for analysis? We are basically analyzing HTML application. Though we get the below error message, the execution gets completed successfully. But we are trying to find the root cause for the below error.

```
ERROR: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.getVersion(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.checkNodeCompatibility(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:144)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.build(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:120)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.initNodeCommand(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:129)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServer(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:105)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServerLazily(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:145)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBasedRulesSensor.execute(EslintBasedRulesSensor.java:92)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:359)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:354)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:317)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:137)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand$ProcessWrapperImpl.start(NodeCommand.java:154)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:73)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried running `node -v` directly on your server (from command-line)? Is Node.js installation directory in your `Path` environment variable?

Comment: @WiktorBednarz, yes doing node -v on command prompt works fine and also I have verified the Path environment variable where node.js installation path is given.

Comment: Do I want to install, NodeJS Plugin on the Jenkins too?

Comment: I had the same error message you had. For me, problem was resolved after adding node installation path to `Path`. At some point SonarQube wants to execute `node -v`, but it cannot find it. It seems it's executed as part of the ESLint plugin.

As I don't use Jenkins myself, I'm not sure installing NodeJS Plugin will help, but it's certainly worth a try!

Answer (score 5):

You have the CSS language plugin installed, which requires Node.js as a prerequisite,  see [plugin documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.9/analysis/languages/css/).

Question comments indicate that you should put the Node.js installation directory on the PATH, but documentation suggests setting the sonar.nodejs.executable properly has the same effect.

Note: as of May 2022, the latest SonarQube (9.4) documentation does not include a separate page detailing CSS analyis, so I linked the documentation for version 8.9 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, but my setup is different.
I use run Jenkins and SonarQube on docker, I've NodeJS plugin installed in Jenkins, but I have to also install NodeJS in the ***Jenkins container***.
Don't forget to restart your Jenkins server, hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Upgrade the nodejs version to altest and try again.

Comment: Answer needs detail around upgrade and configuration.